# combine two regex filters

Tags: regex

I'm a total n00b to using Regex (I'm not a programmer but a support engineer) and in order to solve an issue at work I need to combine two regex's into one regex:

```
^89410[1|2]000[0-9]{10}|893207000500[0-9]{7}$
```

&

```
^893207000[0-9]{10}$
```

Please note I didn't create these two regex's, they were created by developers that no longer work at my job!
Once again, I've never used regex before, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I doubt these ever worked well. Do you know what these patterns should match? Are there exact requirements? BTW, I guess that `^(89410[12]000[0-9]{10}|893207000500[0-9]{7}|893207000[0-9]{10})$` might work for you. Or even `^(89410[12]000[0-9]{10}|893207000(?:500[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{10}))$`

Comment: well this & is misplaced here ... you want matches that either the first pattern or the other will find right? so (?:^89410[1|2]000[0-9]{10}|893207000500[0-9]{7}$)|(?:^893207000[0-9]{10}$)

Answer (score 1):

What your first regex does is test for two possible regex'es (the `|` separates the two). If you want to add other possibilities it's just about adding another one separated by another `|`. (the `^` and `$` in the beginning and the end marks just that - the beginning and the end of the input.)

In your case however, the possible strings (numbers) matching the second part of your first regex is a subset of the ones matching the new regex (your *second*), (Phew... still with me? ;) thus rendering the 2nd part of the 1st unnecessary.

You can see an example of it [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eL9bN2/1). Remove the middle part, and you still will get the same matches.

So, the short answer is -

```
^89410[1|2]000[0-9]{10}|893207000[0-9]{10}$
```

is what you want.

Regards.

Edit:

As Wiktor pointed out (sloppy of me to miss it :P) You need to group the regex'es, or add the start/end markers to each regex separately, like `^89410[1|2]000[0-9]{10}$|^893207000[0-9]{10}$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(89410[12]000[0-9]{10}|893207000500[0-9]{7}|893207000[0-9]{10})$
 ^                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or a shorter, more efficient, but less readable:

```
^(89410[12]000[0-9]{10}|893207000(?:500[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{10}))$
```

The issue was the the `^` and `$` in the first pattern were only applied to the first and last alternatives respectively. You need to use a grouping `(...)`.